# How to extend prop types of Material UI components using Flow when passing through props?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, flowtype

I'd like to add Flow Types to an existing React project which uses Material UI.
I have a number of components which render a Material UI component and pass through any props received. For example:

```
import React from "react";
import IconButton from "@material-ui/core/IconButton";
import backIcon from "assets/icons/Back.svg";

const BackButton = ({ height, ...props }) => (
  <IconButton {...props}>
    <img
      src={backIcon}
      alt="back"
      style={{
        height,
        width: height
      }}
    />
  </IconButton>
);

BackButton.defaultProps = {
  height: "1.5rem"
};

export default BackButton;
```

If I were to define prop types for this, I figure it would look something like

```
type BackButtonProps = IconButtonProps & {
  height: string
}

const BackButton = ({height, ...props}): BackButtonProps => (
  ...
)
```

My issue is that I'm not sure where to get `IconButtonProps` from. I've run `flow-typed install` and have a `flow-typed/npm/@material-ui` folder, but I can't figure out how to import `IconButtonProps`. I've tried the following:

```
import type { IconButtonProps } from "@material-ui/core/IconButton"
```

But the import is unresolved.
Where can I import the prop types of Material UI components from, in order to be able to extend them?

Comment: Code untested, but by looking at https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/master/packages/material-ui/src/IconButton/IconButton.d.ts, I think you could just do `import IconButton, {IconButtonProps} from "@material-ui/core/IconButton";`

Comment: When I try that, I get `Cannot import IconButtonProps because there is no IconButtonProps export in @material-ui/core/IconButton.`
The file you linked appears to be a Typescript typing file, not a Flow Type file

Comment: Oh, sorry, are you using `JavaScript` and not  `TypeScript`?